# Get reason why my guard handled an error in Swift

Tags: swift

I don't know if this question has already been asked partly because I don't know how to formulate it... That's why I create this question with a concrete example to make it clear.

I have a guard statement like this:

```
guard let id = place["place_id"].string,
      let name = place["name"].string,
      let lat = place["geometry"]["location"]["lat"].double,
      let long = place["geometry"]["location"]["lng"].double

}
```

This statement allows me to handle missing datas in a JSON. However, I have much more data to check compared to this example. Therefore, is there a way to find out which one of these data is missing? I mean, can I use the guard statement to output the missing data in my console ?

Hope it's clear. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Decode the JSON with `Decodable` in Swift 4. The decoder tells you exactly what's wrong and where.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like so:

```
guard let id = place["place_id"].string else { 
    print("place_id is nil")
 }
guard let name = place["name"].string else {
    print("name is nil")
}
...
```

Comment: That is what I did, but not so clean....

Comment: As Vadian indicated using Decodable is clean, but you have to learn it.  At least with this, you understand the syntax of the Guard statement.

Comment: well, you end the function or the code after the guard. Depends and what your doing. So you need to set return or continue for loops. Best is codable 